# ARRAY_AGG with STRUCT - IGNORE NULLS

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to aggregate `STRUCT`s into an array where the two fields within the `STRUCT` can be null (they will either both be null nor neither). Using `IGNORE NULLS` in the `ARRAY_AGG` function doesn't work - is there a way to take these null rows out of the resulting array?

My table looks like this:

[image]

And I want my output to look like this, but excluding the null values within the `STRUCT`s:

[image]

Where there is no value for label, language or dtk I still want to include the row but with a blank array - this means I can't prefilter the nulls out as this will result in rows being excluded.

The query I am currently using to get this output looks like this:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(label, language_name) IGNORE NULLS) AS label,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT dtk IGNORE NULLS) AS dtk,
  country_name, category, age_group, gender
FROM
  categoryData
GROUP BY
  country_name, category, age_group, gender
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [IF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if):

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(if(label is not null or language_name is not null, struct(label, language_name), null) IGNORE NULLS) AS label,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT dtk IGNORE NULLS) AS dtk,
  country_name, category, age_group, gender
FROM
  categoryData
GROUP BY
  country_name, category, age_group, gender
```

Comment: Such a simple solution, should have thought of that! Thanks. :)